# Distributed messaging patterns: Why command can have only one listener?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

With regard to [distributed messaging patterns](https://tuhrig.de/messages-vs-events-vs-commands/), I often find that commands or events are distinguished by the fact that a command can have only one listener while an event can have multiple listeners.

I’m wondering why and if that is really true.

If I need to notify someone in many different ways (by email, by fax, by push notification) what's wrong publishing the command `SendNotification` and letting three different subscribers receive the command and handle the notification? One knows how to notify users by mail; the second knows how to notify users by fax; the third knows how notify users by google message cloud.

Comment: https://tuhrig.de/messages-vs-events-vs-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should usually be one *central* authority that decides whether it's appropriate to accept the request for a notification, and then it can farm out the *mechanisms by which that may happen* via other means (including by dedicated mechanism specific commands directed to the correct provider).

Who/What component is responsible for detecting "email decided it wasn't a job for it, fax decided it wasn't a job for it, push decided it wasn't a job for it"? If each component is deciding for itself, it's difficult to discover that no notification ended up being sent.

Basically, you send commands to your *sources of truth*. Hopefully, you only have one of each for each domain.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m wondering why and if that is really true.

In the context of messaging, I don't think that's really true. Messaging is fundamentally a many-to-many design. While the semantics of a command might make it more likely that only one component handles a command message, enforcing a one-to-one relationship defeats part of the benefit of messaging.